# Firefox on Ubuntu 20.04 Amazon Prime Videos not able to play videos.. Is it possible?

Tags: firefox

Firefox on Ubuntu 20.04 Amazon Prime Videos not able to play videos.. Is it possible?
I am messing since hours with workarounds and answers adding ppa's this that etc..

Is it possible to play Amazon Prime Videos with the default Firefox on Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Probhttps://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/enable-drm?as=u&utm_source=inproductably need to enable DRM content:

Comment: tried it.. still no..

Comment: try to install the package ubuntu-restricted-extras with sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras

Comment: @kannzzmm2 i am willing to do that.. can you brief me what is the point that makes amazon video plays with regards to restricted extras plz?

Comment: this package contains commonly used addons like flash player, and to play differentr formats like mp3 format, video etc.. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing the package `ubuntu-restricted-extras` solves the issue, which has addons/codecs for different media formats.

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```